# MUI 5 using styled components with child component props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm converting from MUI 4 to 5. Working on converting from `makeStyles()` to styled components. Is there an example somewhere using the `styled()` method with a component that has child component props? For example, `<ListItemText />` has `primaryTypographyProps` and `secondaryTypographyProps`, both of which I'm setting the inner `className` property for custom styles.

How does something like this...

```
<ListItemText
  {...props}
  primaryTypographyProps={{
    variant: 'body2',
    className: classes.primary,
  }}
  secondaryTypographyProps={{
    variant: 'body1',
    className: classes.secondary,
  }}
/>
```

...convert to something like this?

```
const StyledListItemText = styled(ListItemText)(({ theme }) => ({
  ...???...
}));
```

[Edit] [This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738188/styling-nested-components-in-styled-components) the closest I've been able to find, but it's not quite there. What I'm trying to do is pass it through a props object, rather than whole components.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to verify if this works, but I'm assuming this is the direction I need to go with this:

```
const StyledListItemText = styled(ListItemText)(() => ({
  'MuiListItemText-primary': { ... },
  'MuiListItemText-secondary': { ... },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close!

```
import listItemTextClasses from '@mui/material';

...

const StyledListItemText = styled(ListItemText)(() => ({
  [`& .${listItemTextClasses.primary}`]: {...}
  [`& .${listItemTextClasses.secondary}`]: {...}
}));
```

https://mui.com/base/getting-started/customization/#applying-custom-css-rules