# How do I style elements of a component using styled-components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a component like this:

```
// MyComponent.tsx
export function MyComponent(): React.ReactElement {
  return <Wrapper>
           <Text>
             hello there
           </Text>
           <AnotherText>
             bye bye
           </AnotherText> 
         </Wrapper>
} 

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  color: #FEB240;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
  padding-left: 7rem;
  padding-right: 7rem;
  gap: 2rem;
`;

export const Text = styled.span`
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(28, 33, 120, 1);
`;

export const AnotherText = styled.span`
  color: red;
`;
```

I want to be able to style the wrapper. I tried to like this (from this answer [Styling Nested Components in Styled-Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738188/styling-nested-components-in-styled-components)), but I don't see any change:

```
// AnotherPlace.tsx
const NewlyStyledMyComponent = styled(MyComponent)`
  ${Wrapper} {
    color: brown;
    background: magenta;
   }
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed 2 issues:

1. To style a custom React component (even just so that its nested components can be styled), you always need to take a `className` prop and to apply it on one of your rendered elements, as explained in [styled-components docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component):

> The `styled` method works perfectly on all of your own or any third-party component, as long as they attach the passed `className` prop to a DOM element.

2. To [style nested components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components), the `className` of the parent element must be applied on a *parent* DOM element as well; that is why [JohnLi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74940540/5108796) has to add an extra `<div className={className}>` around the `<Wrapper>`.

But in your case, you could just style `MyComponent` and apply the `className` on the `<Wrapper>`:

```
export function MyComponent({
  className
}: {
  className?: string;
}): React.ReactElement {
  return (
    // Apply className directly on the Wrapper
    <Wrapper className={className}>
      This text can be re-colored
      <Text>hello there can be re-colored if styling nested Text</Text>
      <AnotherText>bye bye</AnotherText>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

const NewlyStyledMyComponent = styled(MyComponent)`
  /* Directly style MyComponent */
  color: brown;
  background: magenta;

  /* Styling of nested components */
  ${Text} {
    color: white;
  }
`;
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-worker-05xmil?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `MyComponent` also need to take (generated) `className` as props and assign it to the root wrapping element to make the nested styles to work as expected.

Simplified live demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-fqzt8h?file=src/App.tsx)

A basic example in `MyComponent`:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface Props {
  className?: string;
}

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background-color: hotpink;
`;

export const Text = styled.span`
  color: #fff;
`;

function MyComponent({ className }: Props) {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <Wrapper>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

And at where it is imported and used:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import MyComponent, { Wrapper, Text } from './MyComponent';

const NewlyStyledMyComponent = styled(MyComponent)`
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  ${Wrapper} {
    background-color: indigo;
  }
  ${Text} {
    color: gold;
  }
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NewlyStyledMyComponent />
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```